# Cannot inject the dependency "modelRepository" at position #0 of "GetModelService" constructor. Reason: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, tsyringe

i've been using **`sequelize-typescript`**, **`tsyringe`** on a refactor work here and i got a pretty interesting bug here.
Well normally all of my repository containers is being registered normally and instanced properly with the follow settings:

- i import the reflect metadata on the root of my application and the `tsyringe` container after it

  ```
  import 'reflect-metadata';
  import 'dotenv/config';
  import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
  ...
  import '@shared/infra/sequelize/index'; // default sequelize connection
  import '@shared/container/index';
  ```
- Inside of container/index is the following code, im using `sequelize-typescript` to craft the repositories.

  ```
  import { container } from 'tsyringe';

  import IUsersRepository from '@modules/users/repositories/IUsersRepositories';
  import UsersRepository from '@modules/users/infra/sequelize/repositories/UserRepository';
  ...
  import IModelRepository from '@modules/model/repositories/IModelRepository';
  import ModelRepository from '@modules/model/infra/sequelize/repositories/ModelRepository';

  container.registerSingleton<IUsersRepository>(
    'UsersRepository',
    UsersRepository,
  );
  ...
  container.registerSingleton<IModelRepository>(
    'ModelRepository',
    ModelRepository,
  );
  ```
- then i do all of the routering with express:

  ```
  import { Router } from 'express';
  import bdDecider from '@shared/infra/http/middlewares/bdDecider';
  import ensureAuthenticated from '@modules/users/infra/http/middlewares/EnsureAuthenticated';
  import UserRouter from '@modules/users/infra/http/routes/user.routes';
  ...
  import ModelRouter from '@modules/model/infra/http/routes/model.routes';

  const routes = Router();

  routes.use('/sessions', SessionRouter);
  routes.use(ensureAuthenticated);
  routes.use(bdDecider); //bdDecider as it says gets the logged on user bdConfig so i can connect to it
  routes.use('/model', ModelRouter);
  ```
- so we go to the route that calls `container.resolve()`

  ```
  import { container } from 'tsyringe';
  import { Response, Request } from 'express';
  import ShowModelsService from '@modules/invoices/services/ShowModelsService';

  export default class ShowModelsController {
    public async show(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
      const { id } = req.params;

      const showModelsService = container.resolve( //it calls the model service
        ShowModelsService,
      );

      const models = await showModelsService.execute(
        id,
      );

      return res.json(models);
    }
  }
  ```
- here is the service that he calls

  ```
  import IModelRepository from '@modules/model/repositories/IModelRepository';
  import AppError from '@shared/errors/AppError';
  import { inject, injectable } from 'tsyringe';
  import IModelDTO from '../dtos/IModelDTO';

  type IResponse = IModelDTO;

  @injectable()
  export default class ShowModelService {
    constructor(
      @inject('ModelRepository')
      private modelRepository: IModelRepository,
    ) {}

    public async execute(id: string): Promise<IResponse> {
      const model = await this.modelRepository.get_models(
        id,
      );

      if (!model) {
        throw new AppError('Model not found!', 404);
      }

      return model;
    }
  }
  ```
- Till there everything is fine and works properly, but when i try to associate that model with another one using `sequelize`. `Tsyringe` stops being able to properly inject the dependencies and gives the title error message. Here it is the models i'm trying to associate.

  ```
  import Model from '@modules/model/infra/sequelize/entities/Model';
  import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
  import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
  import User from '../entities/User';
  export default (sequelize: Sequelize): void => {
  Model.init(
      {
        primary: {
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        camp1: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 2),
        camp2: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
      {
        tableName: 'tbl_model',
        sequelize,
      },
    );
    Model.hasMany(User);
  }
  ```
- if i remove that "`Model.hasMany(User);`" it goes back to normal and the injection happens, i'm very confused to know whats going on...
- by the way here is my model repository

  ```
  import IModelRepository from '@modules/model/repositories/IModelRepository';
  import AppError from '@shared/errors/AppError';
  import { connection } from '@shared/infra/http/middlewares/bdDecider';
  import { Repository } from 'sequelize-typescript';
  import IModelDTO from '@modules/model/dtos/IModelDTO';
  import initModel from '../utils/initInvoice';
  import initUser from '../utils/initItem';
  import Model from '../entities/Model';
  import User from '../entities/User';

  export default class ModelRepository implements IModelRepository {
    private ormRepository: Repository<Model>;

    constructor() {
      if (!connection) {
        throw new AppError(
          `You don't have a client settled on your user credentials or you don't have a client settled or both`,
        );
      }
      initModel(connection); // it Model.init() the model with the hasmany association
      initUser(connection); // it User.init()
      this.ormRepository = connection.getRepository(Model);
    }
    public async get_models(
      id: string,
    ): Promise<IModelDTO | null> {
      const models = await this.ormRepository.findOne({
        where: { id },
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
          },
        ],
      });
      return models;
    }
  }
  ```
- I'm sorry if this is too much information, but i tried to give as much as possible so someone could maybe help me.. But honestly i'm kinda skeptical about finding a solution, probably i'll have to detach this method from this model and try to do it separately. As you noticed i changed the names of the models so i might have misspelled something but don't worry with that there's not misspelling on the actual code because this bug only happens when i add "`Model.hasMany(User);`" to the `initModel()` function. Hopefully someone will be able to help me, any questions i'll be around don't be afraid to ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh well i figured out a solution. Its just better to init the models before calling the `container.resolve()`. For some reason when you try to init a model inside of it looks like it loses the reference and it fails to inject. But all good now :)

```
     constructor() {
        if (!connection) {
          throw new AppError(
            `You don't have a client settled on your user credentials or you don't have a client settled or both`,
          );
        }
    initModel(connection); 
    initUser(connection); 
    this.ormRepository = connection.getRepository(Model);
  }
```

so i just removed the initModel and initUser functions from the repository constructor and putted somewhere else before the `container.resolve()` being called.